Alignment of unit vectors under graph-neighbor constraints with a global vector
Statement
Let $G = (V, E)$ be a connected, unweighted, and undirected graph with $n$ nodes, represented by its adjacency matrix $A$. Suppose each node $i$ is associated with a unit vector $ \mathbf{v}_i \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ on the unit circle, and let $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ also be a unit vector.
We impose the following iterative condition:
$$
\mathbf{v}_i \parallel \sum_{j \in N(i)} \mathbf{v}_j + \mathbf{b}, \quad \forall i \in V,
$$
where $N(i)$ is the set of neighbors of node $i $, and $\parallel$ denotes that $ \mathbf{v}_i$ is parallel to $\sum_{j \in N(i)} \mathbf{v}_j + \mathbf{b}$.
Question
If there exists a $\mathbf{b} $ such that the above condition holds for all $i $, does it follow that all $ \mathbf{v}_i $ align with $\mathbf{b} $? In other words, does $\mathbf{v}_i = \mathbf{b}$ for all $ i $?
Numerical test
Experiments suggest that for any connected graph $G$, starting with arbitrary initial $\mathbf{v}_i$, the system iteratively evolves until all $ \mathbf{v}_i$ align with $\mathbf{b} $. This appears to hold regardless of the graph structure or the initial $\mathbf{v}_i$.
